# Possible Question on Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: continuity

Let $P\left(x\right)=x^{10}+a_2x^8+a_3x^6+a_4x^4+a_2x^2$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. If P(1)=1 and P(2)=-5, then the minimum number of distinct real zeroes of P(x) is?

I think we need to solve this question using Intermediate Value Theorem, but I am not really sure how to implement that over here.

Comment: To see how to implement it, read for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752943/let-fx-x5a-1x4a-2x3a-3x2-be-a-polynomial-function-if-f10-and-f?rq=1).

Comment: The question helped somewhat, but I am still not able to quite understand the solution. Apart from that I think that method wouldn't work on this question as when the function approaches infinity regardless of whether x approaches infinity or -ve infinity.

Comment: $P$ is an even function with a zero at 0, a zero in $(1,2)$ (by IVT), and one in $(2,\infty)$ ($P$ has limit $\infty$ at $\infty$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.